# Need help with proof of existence of $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I am working my way through the proofs on [this page](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/analysis/Lectures/L5.html). I am stuck on "4. The real number $\sqrt{2}$ exists." It begins:

> We will get $\sqrt{2}$ as the least upper bound of the set $A = \{q\in Q | q^2 < 2 \}$. We know that A is bounded above (by 2 say)...

How do we know this? How might I prove it?

---

**EDIT (11 hours later)**

I think I may have it.

Suppose $x\cdot x\leq2$.

Suppose to the contrary that $x>2$.

$x=2+d$ for $d>0$

$x\cdot x = 4+4d+d\cdot d <2$

$2+4d+d\cdot d<0$

This is contradicted by the fact that $d>0$.

Answer (score 7):

If $q^2 < 2$, then clearly $q^2 < 4$. If $q^2 < 4$, what can you conclude about $q$?

Answer (score 1):

$2$ is an upper bound of that set since for any $q$ with $q^2<2$, clearly $q\ge 2$ is impossible (do you see why?).

Comment: I am allowing myself only the axioms for the real numbers given at the link (field axioms, etc.) I am trying to write a formal version of the proof. I "know"   from experience that 2 will be an upper bound, but how to formally prove it?

Comment: if $q\ge 2$, then $qq\ge 2q\ge 2\cdot 2=4>2$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x>2$. We obviously have $2>0$. Now from $x>y>0$ we know $x^2>y^2$. Thus $x^2>2^2=4$. However if $x^2>4$, then obviousy we don't have $x^2<2$, and therefore $x\notin A$.

So we have proved that whenever $x>2$, then $x\notin A$. Therefore if $x\in A$, then $x\le 2$. But that's exactly the definition of an upper bound, and therefore $2$ is an upper bound of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can say that $\sqrt{2}$ is not imaginary. Now $\sqrt{1}<\sqrt{2}<\sqrt{4}$ thus $1<\sqrt{2}<2$ so it has to exist between those two numbers , and it is real so it exists.

Comment: How can you say those things before you prove that $\sqrt{2}$ exists?

Comment: You seem to already assume quit a lot about $\sqrt 2$....

Comment: i see your argument , maybe i can use the $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and prove it is increasing and then write the inequality ?

Comment: and what precisely $f(x)=\sqrt x$ is then? You are trying to argue $\sqrt 2$ exists by arguing that $\sqrt x$ exists for which $x$ exactly?